# How do I clear a Django template cache at a specific time (e.g. midnight)?

Tags: django, caching

I understand that Django's cache functions expire after a specified time interval has elapsed (e.g. 1 minute, 1 hour, etc.), but I have some content that changes on a daily basis (e.g. "message of the day").  Ideally this would be cached for 24 hours, but if I set the timeout to 24 hours there's no guarantee that the cache will expire precisely at midnight.  What is the best practice for handling this situation?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to _browser cache_ dynamic pages. You should only cache your static files, not the whole page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two easy options spring to mind, both involving a scheduled task that needs to run at (say) midnight.

1) Get ahead of the game: Schedule some code to run (eg a custom management command) that asks for your 'message of the day' content at midnight, with an 24hr expiry. (This assumes the relevant cache key is not set yet)

2) Go nuclear: schedule a cache purge at midnight

or, combining the two:

Don't go nuclear, just schedule a call to only delete the MOTD key (eg cache.delete('motd_key') at midnight, then cache the new one instead.

Alternatively, if you use Redis as your cache backend, you could cache the MOTD, then make an [EXPIREAT](http://redis.io/commands/EXPIREAT) call to set that cached MOTD entry to expire at 23:59:59. redis.py will let you do that in a Pythonic way.

If you're using Memcached as your backend, you don't get that level of control.

(And if you're using locmem://, you're Doing It Wrong ;o) )

Comment: These are some great options (e.g. a scheduled task or Redis).  I had not heard of Redis before and will check that out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just implement a custom cache instead of introducing another side effect like scheduled jobs?

Create a cache class like so:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from django.core.cache.backends.locmem import LocMemCache


class MidnightCacher(LocMemCache):

    def __init__(self, name, params):
        super().__init__(name, params)

    def get_backend_timeout(self, timeout=None):
        # return time until midnight
        return (datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).timestamp()
```

Configure your cache in settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'midnight': {
        'BACKEND': 'backend.midnight_cache.MidnightCacher',
        'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake',
    }
}
```

And finally, decorate your view:

```
@cache_page(1, cache="midnight")
def get_comething(request):
    pass
```